# Additional Drivers for AMD Graphic Card have not been installing

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, fglrx, 14.10

I have a trouble with my Ubuntu 14.10. I want to install additional driver for my AMD graphic card but when I choose fglrx-updates in "Software & Updates" -> "Additional Drivers" and press "Apply Changes" nothing is done. I use Main server for installing software, and the checkbox "Proprietary drivers for devices (restricted)" is enabled.

I thought about installing the "fglrx-installer-updates" package or downloading from the official site, but I remember with manual installed drivers on Fedora and want to avoid similar troubles.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. My graphic card was detected as "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]: Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]".

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you install the default option of fglrx on ubuntu repositories instead fglrx-updates. Follow the instructions below to solve this issue.

On the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>)

Uninstall and remove all configuration files:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
```

Install the proprietary package on Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
```

Create a new xorg.conf

```
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

Restart the PC

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: When I've tried to type `sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle` I got the message `The following packages have unmet dependencies: fgrlx: fglrx-core but it is not going to be installed. E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` When I've tried to type `sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-core fglrx-amdcccle` the packages `ocl-icd-libopencl1 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 wine  wine1.6 wine1.6-amd64 wine1.6-i386:i386` were able for removing.

Comment: did you performed sudo apt-get purge fglrx* before? perform `sudo apt-get autoremove; sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f fglrx fglrx-amdcccle`

Comment: The problem was because of `wine`. This package had broken a whole installation process. I just removed it and could install `fglrx`.